When using Azure.ResourceManager .net library, how to import a certificate from KeyVault to an AppService?
I already asked this question here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/46369, but since I haven't gotten any response there yet I hope someone on SO will have a clue.
Library name and version
Azure.ResourceManager 1.12.0
Query/Question
I cannot find a working way to import a certificate from KeyVault when creating/updating an AppService (WebSite).
I'm am NOT using the certificate for TLS/SSL host binding. The certificate is used by the application code to authenticate with a database service.
I have tried this:
// First set up WebSiteData (a function app in my case)
var webSiteData = new WebsiteData(...);

new CertificateClient(new Uri(_keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy vaultCertificate = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync("cert-name");

webSiteData.HostNameSslStates.Add(new HostNameSslState
{
    Name = vaultCertificate.Name,
    ThumbprintString = vaultCertificate.Properties.X509ThumbprintString,
    SslState = HostNameBindingSslState.SniEnabled
});

var webSite = (await resourceGroup.GetWebSites().CreateOrUpdateAsync(
    WaitUntil.Completed,
    "site-name",
    webSiteData
)).Value;

I haven't found any example code except similar to the webSiteData.HostNameSslStates.Add. If I add the certificate through the portal it works perfect, I just need to be able to do the same using Azure.ResourceManager
What I'm trying to do is the same as the Azure CLI command:
az webapp config ssl import --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyWebapp --key-vault MyKeyVault --key-vault-certificate-name MyCertificateName

This works fine. But how to perform the same using Azure.ResourceManager in .net code?

If you run that CLI command with --debug, you can see what requests it makes. That might help with figuring out how to replicate it with the library.

Still facing the issue? @Trygve

@Jahnavi, I didn't have time to test your code yesterday, will give it a try today. Thanks!

@jahnavi, still haven't solved this. Could you share a working project to make sure I have the same dependencies you have?

Are you still facing the issue. @Trygve

@Jahnavi, yes. I call the command line "az webapp config ssl import" from c# instead. But I found an even better approach for my use case is to load the certificate directly from azure key vault instead of importing it to the app and then load the cert by thumbprint

I finally got a working example from the Azure ResourceManager github project:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/46369#issuecomment-2469693141
Basically, you do something like this:
//Obtain the secret value of the certificate and convert it into a byte array format PFX certificate
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync("Your_Vault_Certificate_Name");
var pfxBlob = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value.Value);

//Create a AppCertificateResource
var appCertificateCollection = resourceGroup.GetAppCertificates();
var appCertificateName = "certificateName";
var appCertificateData = new AppCertificateData(AzureLocation.EastUS2)
{
     ServerFarmId = appServicePlan.Id,//Used to specify webapp
     PfxBlob = pfxBlob,
};
var appCertificate = (await appCertificateCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, appCertificateName, appCertificateData)).Value;

Make sure to have NuGet package Azure.Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets in the project and import it in a "using" statement


When using Azure.ResourceManager .net library, how to import a certificate from KeyVault to an AppService?

Use below given code to retrieve and import a certificate from Key vault to an app service.
Reference MS Doc for creating and retrieving a certificated using .NET Azure Key vault certificate client library.
Certificate retrieval code snippet:
namespace key_vault_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string certificateName = "mynewCertificate";
            var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
            string AppserviceName = "appsjah";
            var resourceGroupName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME");
            var SubscriptionID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());


            Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving your certificate from {keyVaultName}.");
            var certificate = await client.GetCertificateAsync(certificateName);
            var secret = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync(certificateName);
            string Base64 = secret.Value.Value;
            byte[] Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64);
            string certPassword = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("retrieved from Key Vault.");

Complete code:
Program.cs:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.Core;

namespace key_vault_app
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string certificateName = "mynewCertificate";
            var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
            string AppserviceName = "appsjah";
            var resourceGroupName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME");
            var SubscriptionID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
            var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

            var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());


            Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving your certificate from {keyVaultName}.");
            var certificate = await client.GetCertificateAsync(certificateName);
            var secret = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync(certificateName);
            string Base64 = secret.Value.Value;
            byte[] Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64);
            string certPassword = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("retrieved from Key Vault.");
            var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            
            var subscription = armClient.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}"));
            var resourceGroup = subscription.GetResourceGroup(resourceGroupName);
            var webSite = await resourceGroup.Value.GetWebSites().GetAsync(AppserviceName);
            var appServiceLocation = webSite.Value.Data.Location;
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading to App Service...");
            var certData = new AppCertificateData(new AzureLocation(appServiceLocation))
            {
                PfxBlob = Bytes,
                Password = certPassword
            };
            var certCollection = webSite.Value;

            var certRes = await certCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil().Completed, certificateName, certData);
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate uploaded to App Service.");
        }
    }
}



Additional References:
AppServiceCertificates,
Azure.ResourceManager Library

I cannot get this part to work:
var certCollection = webSite.Value;
var certRes = await certCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil().Completed, certificateName, certData);

Are you sure that var certCollection = webSite.Value; is correct? WebSiteResource doesn't have any CreateOrUpdateAsync method. Also, variable name certCollection seems very misleading. Did you mean something else?

What is the exact error you are getting? @Trygve

I don't find the properties/methods that you are using in your code.
var certCollection = webSite.Value;
        var certRes = await certCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil().Completed, certificateName, certData);

certCollection here is an instance of WebSiteResource, which has no method CreateOrUpdateAsync that accepts the arguments listed in your code

@NaveenSharma, unfortunately, i never got the solution in this answer to work. I got a working solution at the Azure.ResourceManager github however (see my answer below)
